# Loading salesforce info to my local host site

Tags: salesforce

just as a heads up I am 100% new to salesforce, only hearing about it yesterday. I have been assigned the task of writing an API to pull customer emails into our new website that is currently on my local host. I know the sobject name of the emails is a string called emails. However I think I am missing some major fundamentals despite reading a bunch of salesforce documentation pages.

When I log into our site I do not see a database (like I would have expected) I just see the many objects for our cusomters. I just can't seem to understand where I am supposed to write this "api" that I was told to do, or how to use it once it is written somewhere. I apologize for having no clue what I am doing regarding this, can someone please explain the basics of pulling data from it (currently on windows running apache if this matters, using HTTPS).

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you will need to implement REST API services on Salesforce side and work with them from your app. If you are totally new with Salesforce just try to read [Learn Salesforce Basics](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/14/en-us/sfdc/pdf/basics.pdf) or use [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en) interactive courses.

When you will understand a bit SF, you will need to learn how implement Salesforce REST API, here is the related [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm).